# Exercise 10. Groups and Covering spaces. Lima

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mobius-band

Let $X$ be the space obtained from the sphere $S^2$ by gluing the north pole  to the south pole, let $Y=\mathbb{R}^3-S^1$, where $S^1=\left\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1\right\}$ and let $Z$ be the union of a torus of revolution with a disk whose boundary is the smallest of the parallels of the torus. Prove that $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ have the same homotopy type.

How can I prove that $Z$ have the same homotopy type with to $X$ or $Y$?

Comment: $X$ is a deformation retract of $Z$ (collapse the disk to a point). But $Y$ does not have the same homotopy type as them, since $Y$ is equivalent to a circle, while $X$ and $Z$ have nontrivial $\pi_2$.

Comment: Partial answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3040181.

Answer (score 2):

## Goal

Provide a plan along with some guidance for the reader to complete the details.

**Notation:**  $\sigma=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. $Y=\mathbb R^3\setminus\{\sigma=1,\;z=0\}$.

### Plan

**Step 1.** Define $B_2=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\le4\}$. Replace $Y$ with $\bar Y=B_2\setminus\{\sigma=1,\;z=0\}$.

**Step 2.** Define $(0,0,z)\sim(0,0,0)$. Replace $\bar Y$ with $\bar Y/{\sim}$.

**Step 3.** Replace $\bar Y/{\sim}$ with $T^*=\{(\sigma-1)^2+z^2\le1\}\setminus\{\sigma=1,\;z=0\}$.

**Step 4.** Replace $T^*$ with $T=\{(\sigma-1)^2+z^2=1\}$.

### Guidance

**Step 1.** Put $\rho=\sqrt{\sigma^2+z^2}$.
$$
f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}
   \tfrac{2}{\rho}(x,y,z)    &\rho\ge 2,\\
   (x,y,z)          &\rm otherwise.
\end{cases}
$$

**Step 2.** Define $g\colon\bar Y/{\sim}\to\bar Y$ as $g\colon[x,y,z]\mapsto(x,y,\frac{\sigma}{2}z)$.

**Step 3.** Write $\zeta=\sqrt{1-(\sigma-1)^2}$. Define $h\colon\bar Y/{\sim}\to T^*$ as
$$
h([x,y,z]) = \begin{cases}
  (x,y,\zeta)   &z\ge\zeta,\\
  (x,y,z)       &-\zeta\le z\le\zeta,\\
  (x,y,-\zeta)  &z\le-\zeta.
\end{cases}
$$

**Step 4.** Write $\xi=\sqrt{(\sigma-1)^2+z^2}$. Define $r\colon T^*\to T$ as
$$
r(x,y,z) = \begin{cases}
   \tfrac{1}{\xi}(x-x/\sigma,y-y/\sigma,z)+(x/\sigma,y/\sigma,0)   &\sigma\ne0,\\
   (0,0,0)  &\sigma=0.
\end{cases}
$$

### To do

1. Draw pictures to understand the idea.
2. Prove the continuity of the functions defined above.
3. Use the functions to build homotopies between domain and codomain.
4. Complete the solution to the problem. (see also [How can I prove that the horn torus and $\mathbb{T} \cup D_1$ have the same homotopy type?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1524479/269050))